# jQuery when div is clicked update input field issue

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I'm rather new to jquery so this may be the issue.  I have a script that outputs several divs all with different text data in them.  I would like it when I click one of them that an input field's value is updated to that text currently I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.results]").click(function() {
        data= this.text();
        $("#updateme").val(data);                                       });  
 });
 </script>

    <p>   <label>Field
        <input type="text" name="updateme" id="updateme">   </label> </p> 

<a href="#" class="results">Florida</a>
<a href="#" class="results">Florida 2</a>
<a href="#" class="results">Florida 3</a>
```

How can I make it so that whatever link is clicked that is the data that gets updated into the input's value?   I can get it to take one or I can script out different cases of each changing the class name but I think there has to be a way where it references whatever link is being clicked instead of what it's currently doing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be nice if you checked the timestamp before you chose the correct answer.

Comment: the time stamps were both at 1:18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your solution is correct but there are some syntax errors. `data= this.text();` should be `var data = $(this).text()` and `$("a.results]")` should be `$("a.results")`

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of your bracket: $("a.results]") - should be $("a.results").  That may help.